# NUnit - Is there a way to find out which test case is being ran at a point in time?

Tags: c#, nunit

In an attempt to reduce the amount of tests I have within a single class I am using NUnits `TestCase` attribute to feed a number of testcases into a single test method.

However the output of each of my tests is going to differ depending on which testcase parameter has failed the test. For example if the testcase is `"street", "town$", "state"` and within the test it is `town` that fails due to the presence of a symbol, then the string `town is invalid` will be returned by the method being tested.

However if the next `TestCase` is `"street$", "town", "state"`, then the returned string will be `street is invalid`.

I need a way to be able to determine which TestCase is being executed by the test method at a single point in time. Is there any way this is possible within NUnit?

I did have the idea of passing in a variable along with the TestCase parameters that changes every case, e.g.:

```
"street1", "town1", "state1", 1 // <-- this int changes with each test case
"street2", "town2", "state2", 2
"street3", "town3", "state3", 3
```

But this seems like a very hacky way of getting it to work, is there a better alternative?

Comment: Which NUnit version are you using?

Comment: @S.Spieker 3.10.1

Answer (score 0):

I would add a fourth argument representing the expected return from the method being tested:

`"street$", "town", "state", "street is invalid"`